# Javascript: Find and highlight all occurrences of keyword. Case insensitive, part and complete words

Tags: javascript, search, find, highlight

I am trying add a search bar to one of my web screens in order to search through and highlight all occurrences of the keyword searched for. Through an example I found here on stack overflow I can search through any text hard-coded in the text but I have a file being read in to the window that I want to be able to search through and highlight in the same way. Would anyone be able to help me?

Javascript

```
var MyApp_SearchResultCount;
var currSelected;

function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {
    MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;
    currSelected = -1;
  if (element) {
    if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node
      while (true) {
        var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
        var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

        if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

        var span = document.createElement("span");
        var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
        span.appendChild(text);
        span.setAttribute("class","MyAppHighlight");
        span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        span.style.color="black";
        text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
        element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
        var next = element.nextSibling;
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
        element = text;
        MyApp_SearchResultCount++;  // update the counter

      }
    } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
      if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
        for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
          MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function goNext(){
    jump(1);
}
function goPrev(){
    jump(-1);
}

function jump(howHigh){
        prevSelected = currSelected;
    currSelected = currSelected + howHigh;

    if (currSelected < 0){
        currSelected = MyApp_SearchResultCount + currSelected;
    }
    if (currSelected >= MyApp_SearchResultCount){
        currSelected = currSelected - MyApp_SearchResultCount;
    }

    prevEl = document.getElementsByClassName("MyAppHighlight")[prevSelected];
    if (prevEl){
        prevEl.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    }
    el = document.getElementsByClassName("MyAppHighlight")[currSelected]; 
    el.style.backgroundColor="green";
    el.scrollIntoView(true); //thanks techfoobar
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="divSection" class="divSection" onclick="selectAll(this)">
        <%=bean.getValue("configText")%>

        <p> BlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlah </p>
</div>
```

Please see this example http://jsfiddle.net/catherinepaul01/eb344g2c/2/

NB. If anyone knows of a way you can do this using dojo, that would be even better!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have addressed the problem in the wrong way.

If I want to be able to highlight all the occurrences of a word within a text, I would make a unique HTML text object, and with a *single* instruction I would do it!

```
str = str.replace(word, "<b>" && word && "</b>");
```